# Shell exec and pipes

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, exec, pipe

I'm using bash, and as I understand it, exec followed by a command is supposed to replace the shell without creating a new process. For example,

```
exec echo hello
```

has the appearance of printing "hello" and then immediately exiting, because after echo is done, the shell process isn't there to return to anymore.

If I put this as part of a pipeline - for instance,

```
exec echo hello | sed 's/hell/heck/'
```

or

```
echo hello | exec sed 's/hell/heck/'
```

my expectation is that, similarly, the shell would terminate as a result of its process being replaced away. This is not what happens in reality, though - both the commands above print "hecko" and return to the shell normally, just as if the word "exec" wasn't there. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is sentence in bash manual:

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in
>   a subshell).

So in both examples two processes are spawned by the pipeline first and 'exec' is executed inside one of spawned process - without impact on shell executing the pipeline.

Comment: Right.  Another example of not-influencing the mother shell would be to use parentheses to create a sub shell:  `(exec echo hello)`.